# Can Robotium test features like in-app billing, social share, intents, etc.?

Tags: android, android-testing, android-espresso, robotium

I found literary zero tutorials on how to use Robotium to test in-app billing. So I am not sure if this is a general knowledge that Robotium cannot test 3rd party apps or Robotium community is not as large as I thought.

Namely, I would like to be able to write Robotium tests for features like:

- in-app billing
- social share (Facebook, Twitter, etc.)
- other 3rd-party apps that we access via `Intents`

So can Robotium be used for testing features like I listed above?

Comment: Appium might be your choice. Think it as a black box testing tool.

Answer (score 1):

Well, `Robotium` is really simple, so also limited, testing framework.

According to your question, it's possible to test `Intent` with `Robotium`, but it's pretty hard to archive in simple way. Check: [Using Robotium with intents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15617173/using-robotium-with-intents)

I would recommend you learn  about `Android Testing Support`, library especially about `Espresso` and `uiatomator` testing frameworks.

Check this site: https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/

The first one is pretty similar to `Robotium`, but it has some artifacts like `espresso-intents` or `espresso-contrib` libraries, so it has a way more testing possibilities. But... it also has disadvantages:

- no option to take a screenshot, you need to have 3rd party library to do it
- some dependencies confict with `espresso-contrib` library
- like `Robotium` `Espresso` UI testing framework doesn't see more than actual application context, so it's pretty impossible to test notifications, sharing intents or open another app during the test.

For this purposes use another Google's testing framework `uiautomator`, which is described as:

> UI Automator is a UI testing framework suitable for cross-app
>   functional UI testing across system and installed apps.

Here you would find how to use it with Espresso: http://qathread.blogspot.com/2015/05/espresso-uiautomator-perfect-tandem.html

I'm prety sure that using both made you to achieve waht you expect.

Hope it would help